# Setting InfoPath form name for printing as PDF?

Tags: forms, pdf-generation, infopath, infopath-2007

We have some custom print code to print an Infopath form on the user's default printer as well as a server-based PDF printer for loading into a document management system. This is working perfectly, but we would like to control the name of the generated PDF file. The PDF print utility can automatically generate a file name using various parameters such as file name, current date/time, etc. Since we cannot programmatically interface with the PDF print utility, the easiest way to control the name of the generated file would be to set the file name in InfoPath and allow the utility to append a date/time stamp.

I have tried setting the form caption as described in the forum thread [here](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/6049/22478.aspx) and setting the Save As file name as described in the forum thread [here](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/7846/28723.aspx), but regardless, the PDF print utility still uses the default form name (Form1, Form2, etc.). Is there another way to set the form name in code?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an InfoPath PDF Converter that you have more control over via a Web Services API?

Have a look at the [PDF Conversion Services](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-Services/summary.aspx) as well as the [PDF Converter for SharePoint](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-for-SharePoint/summary.aspx). It deals quite well with InfoPath.

Some additional links

- [Converting using a Web Service call](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/converting-office-files-to-pdf-format.html)
- [Converting InfoPath files from a workflow](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/batch-print-infopath-forms-using-pdf.html).

Note that I have worked on this product, so I am obviously biased. It works great though.